# Spring batch 5 does not start job automatically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm upgrading a job from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3, which also bumps spring batch to spring batch 5.

I'm having an issue where the job no longer starts automatically. This is not a scheduled or asynchronous job, it's simply run as a jar. Preferably I'd run it something like this if possible(which worked fine in previous versions):

```
java -jar MyJobApp.jar --batch.input-file="/path/to/file/filename.xml" --spring.config.additional-location=file:/path/to/config/externalPropertyFile.yml
```

I have my own database tables for logging batch statuses etc, so I need to configure the job to either *not* use the default batch tables at all, or alternatively just stick them into an in-memory db. I'm persisting what I need through a JobListener.

The spring migration guide mentions this "A bean that is annotated with `@EnableBatchProcessing` or that extends Batch’s `DefaultBatchConfiguration` can now be defined to tell the auto-configuration to back off, allowing the application to take complete control of how Batch is configured."

I'm assuming this is the issue, but as mentioned I need to configure a datasource specific for the JobRepository, and I'm unsure how I can achieve this without using any of these configuration options.

My current setup is something like this:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchProps::class, WebClientProps::class)
@SpringBootApplication
class MyJobApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    exitProcess(SpringApplication.exit(runApplication<MyJobApp>(*args)))
}
```

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
  application:
    name: MyJobApp
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: true
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
class BatchConfig(
    private val reader: PackageDataReader,
    private val processor: PackageDataProcessor,
    private val writer: OrderWriter,
) {

    @Bean
    fun job(listener: JobNotificationListener,
            jobRepository: JobRepository,
            transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager,
            ioStep: Step): Job = JobBuilder(JOB_NAME, jobRepository)
        .listener(listener)
        .flow(ioStep)
        .end()
        .build()


    @Bean
    fun ioStep(jobRepository: JobRepository, transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager): Step = StepBuilder(STEP_NAME, jobRepository)
        .chunk<PackageData, List<OrderType>>(1, transactionManager)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build()

    // We don't want the spring batch metadata tables in our db, so we just stick these into an in-memory db
    @Bean
    fun batchDataSource(): DataSource {
        return EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
            .generateUniqueName(true).build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun batchTransactionManager(): JdbcTransactionManager? {
        return JdbcTransactionManager(batchDataSource())
    }
}
```

I've tried using `EnableBatchProcessing` to configure it declaratively, and I've tried extending `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and overriding `getDataSource` and `getTransactionManager`. I'm assuming I could use something like a `CommandLineRunner` to manually launch the job with an autowired JobLauncher, but this does not feel like the correct way of doing it. The job runs fine in my integration tests which uses a `SimpleJobLauncher` through `JobLauncherTestUtils`.

Logs when running the job:

```
2023-03-03T11:17:05.041+01:00 DEBUG 20592 --- [           main] MyJobApp : Running with Spring Boot v3.0.2, Spring v6.0.4
2023-03-03T11:17:05.041+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] MyJobApp : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2023-03-03T11:17:05.611+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Finished Spring Batch infrastructure beans configuration in 6 ms.
2023-03-03T11:17:07.133+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:3df4e81c-eff0-45fc-a9f2-9b97f721b113;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2023-03-03T11:17:07.433+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2023-03-03T11:17:07.499+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-03-03T11:17:07.513+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-03-03T11:17:07.519+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2023-03-03T11:17:07.743+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] MyJobbApp : Started MyJobApp in 3.28 seconds (process running for 4.247)
2023-03-03T11:17:07.755+01:00  INFO 20592 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:3df4e81c-eff0-45fc-a9f2-9b97f721b113;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. With Spring Boot 3, the batch auto-configuration (including the automatic job execution at startup) is disabled when adding `@EnableBatchProcessing` or extending `DefaultBatchConfiguration`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured. Do you know if there's a way I can configure a datasource specifically for the jobrepository without using any of these? Alternatively, configure it to start automatically. Or am I expected to start a job manually now? I've solved this for now using a CommandLineRunner.

Comment: And if I'm supposed to run in manually, what is the best practice way? I know there's a CommandLineJobRunner you can use to run a job from the terminal/shell, but it sounds a bit weird to me that they're "enforcing" this way of running a configured job. Sorry for the amount of questions, it just feels like I'm not using Spring Batch in a niche enough way that this should be an issue, hehe.

Comment: For the data source, you can initialize it with a `DataSourceInitializer`. For the job execution at startup, you can declare a bean of type `JobLauncherApplicationRunner` in your application context.